# d3js removing a transition of an element

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I have a SVG image (alpha) where I want to show some control options group on mouseover and hide them on mouse out.

Let's say I have the  image alpha in `x=100, y=100`. I have a predefined tooltip classed group in my svg with the style 'visibility':'hidden'. 
I change the style to visible and I set its x,y coordinates to `alpha.attr('x')-20` , `alpha.attr('y')-20` . So that it comes in the left corner of the image. But when I mouseout from the image the group hides itself, to overcome that issue I gave a delay with the `setTimeOut()` function. But when I mouse over to the control group it changes it style to hidden because of the delay.

I tried using the `d3.transition` but I couldn't figure out how to remove it once I hover the control group.

I do not know how to overcome the issue and achieve my requirement. can anyone help me?

```
d3.select('#svg')
    .append('g')
    .attr('id', 'playground')
    .append('image')
    .attr('class', 'tooltip')
    .attr('width', 20)
    .attr('height', 20)
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 0)
    .attr('xlink:href', base_url + '/assets/svg/api_lbs_color.svg')
    .style('visibility', 'hidden')
    .on('mouseover', function () {
        d3.select(this).style('visibility','visible');
    })
    .on('mouseout', function () {
        d3.select(this).style('visibility','hidden');

    });

playGround
            .append('image')
            .attr('width', 32)
            .attr('height', 32)
            .attr('x', d3.mouse(this)[0])
            .attr('y', d3.mouse(this)[1])
            .attr('xlink:href', curr.attr('xlink:href'))
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {  // the mouseover event
                console.log('mouse over playgrround operator');

                var curr = d3.select(this);

                d3.select('.tooltip')
                    .attr('x', curr.attr('x') - 20)
                    .attr('y', curr.attr('y') - 20)
                    .style('visibility', 'visible')
                ;


            })
            .on('mouseout', function () {

                setTimeout(function () {
                    d3.select('.tooltip')
                        .style('visibility', 'hidden')

                }, 1000);


            })
        ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly understand the functionality you want but I think I've had a similar problem in the past. You should be using the `mouseenter` and `mouseexit` events instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`, that will allow the tooltip to stay visible while the cursor is inside the image element.